# DataGridView select only certain number of column vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have DataGridView1 that contain n number of column  i want user to select the column that he want to save then i save it ..(done)

The problem here that i want the user to select only 3 column and on four column  give user massage that he/she have to select only three.

To unselect the last one i use `DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick` Event and I present the message but can not find anything like `DataGridView1.SelectColumn = False`

```
If DataGridView1.SelectedColumns.Count > 3 Then
    MsgBox("You have to choose  3 columns only")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: This may be a stupid questions, but do you really mean "columns" or is the user really selecting rows?

Comment: No i mean "columns" there property in grid that allow you to select  columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced you can count the selected columns that way. Anyway, here's a way to use the args of the event to achieve what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    If DataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 3 Then
        MsgBox("You cannot select more than 3 columns.")
        DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView).Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I used a `DirectCast` to get the sender to behave as the datagridview (which it is) because this way I could attach this event to several different dtagridviews, but if you dislike that form you can always use `DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Selected = False` instead.

Also, I use the `e.ColumnIndex` to unselect the last column the user clicked on because I though that it was what you were trying to do, but you can change this comportment for something more suitable to your needs as you now know how to unselect columns.

Have fun!